# Three-way interaction in regression does not show the interaction terms and estimates

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, interaction

I'm running a linear regression model with a 3-way interaction, and the model runs, but it does not give me the actual interactions, how can I check if there's any interaction between the 3 terms (smart, behave and grades)?

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Conformity_pref ~ Smart * Behave * Grades + (1 | PID)
   Data: MV_final

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  8310.7   8340.2  -4151.4   8302.7    11585 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.62796 -0.11064  0.07686  0.11559  2.22275 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PID    (Intercept) 20.66    4.545   
Number of obs: 11589, groups:  PID, 1295

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.83492    0.30598   12.53   <2e-16 ***
Smart       -0.81602    0.07850  -10.39   <2e-16 ***
Behave       1.15429    0.08672   13.31   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) Smart 
Smart  -0.228       
Behave -0.005  0.415
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 5 columns / coefficients
```

I expect prediction terms such as Smart x Behave, Behave x Grades, Grades x Smart.

Comment: Can you please share the code (and ideally data using `dput()`) that you used to create these outputs? It makes it much easier for other to help if we can recreate your results.

Comment: `interact_model<- glmer(Conformity_pref ~ Smart*Behave*Grades + (1 | PID) , data = MV_final, family=binomial(link = "logit"))`
`summary(interact_model)`

All values are binary (1,0), except for PID (0-1295)
`dput(head(MV_final[, c("Conformity_pref", "PID", "Smart", "Behave", "Grades")]))`
structure(list(Conformity_pref = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PID = c("10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10"), Smart = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Behave = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Grades = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))